# Setting pointers to null value

Tags: c, pointers

This code under returns "segmention fault".

```
struct aluno
{
    char nome[80];
    float nota;
};

struct classe
{
    struct classe* aluno_anterior;
    struct classe* aluno_posterior;
    struct aluno aluno;
};

struct classe *alunos;

void inicializar_classe(void)
{
    alunos->aluno_anterior = NULL; //here occurs the segmentation fault
    alunos->aluno_posterior = NULL;
}
```

How can I initialize the fields aluno_anterior and aluno_posterior to NULL correctly?

Comment: You have to initialize `alunos` first.

Comment: A pointer needs something to point to. It's nothing other than a memory address. You cannot drive to a random address and deliver a package to the resident that lives on the 3rd floor, because there may not be a 3 story building at that address, or it might not be a residence, or it might be uninhabited.

Answer (score 2):

In the code shown, `alunos` is initialized by default to a null pointer. It points “nowhere,” so `alunos->aluno_anterior` is invalid code. `alunos->aluno_anterior` means “The `aluno_anterior` member in the structure that `alunos` points to,” but `alunos` does not point to any structure, so using that expression is invalid.

To fix that, allocate enough memory for a `struct classe` and set `alunos` to point to that memory:

```
alunos = malloc(sizeof *alunos);
if (!alunos)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

To declare the identifiers used above, insert:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

in the source code, outside of any function and before the identifiers are used.